# SwiftUI Remove inner shadow

Tags: swiftui, shadow

How can the **inner** blue shadow be removed, keeping inside **transparent**?

```swift
Circle()
.frame(width: 30, height: 30, alignment: .center)
.padding()
.overlay(
    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
        .strokeBorder(Color.primary, lineWidth: 2)
        .shadow(color: Color.blue.opacity(1), radius: 3, x: 3, y: 3)
)
```

[image]

Comment: As an option, you can fill background with a solid color

Comment: Filling the background with solid color removes transparency. Not an option here.
The Circle in the view will actually come from a view below in a ZStack.

Comment: A custom SVG is likely the only way.

Answer (score 7):

This solution look overloaded, but here we have 3 layers: shadow, mask and stroke.

```swift
Circle()
    .frame(width: 30, height: 30, alignment: .center)
    .padding()
    .overlay(
        ZStack {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20) // shadow layer
                .shadow(color: Color.blue.opacity(1), radius: 3, x: 3, y: 3)
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20) // mask layer
                .blendMode(.destinationOut)
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20) // stroke layer
                .strokeBorder(Color.primary, lineWidth: 2)
        }
            .compositingGroup()
    )
```

[image]

Check this article for more details [How to apply a reverse mask in SwiftUI](https://www.fivestars.blog/articles/reverse-masks-how-to/)